# Can't edit customer in Magento 1.9

Tags: customer-attribute

I'm getting this odd error when I try to edit a customer
Not something I've come across before and don't even know what `bakerloo_payment` is. Thought it could it be something with Sage payments installation?

> Source model `bakerloo_payment/source_paymentmethods` not found for
>   attribute `bakerloo_payment_methods`

Comment: Disable 'bakerloo_payment' module

Comment: Hi, that's the thing I can't find it. Where would this be, as we haven't created this attribute so it's thrown us somewhat?

Comment: you can look it in app/etc/modules folder there should be a file with name of above module something like 'bakerloo_payment.xml i not sure but you can try.

Comment: Did try that but it doesn't exist there? Puzzling I know.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the database, find out which customer attribute uses that source model:

```
SELECT `attribute_id`, `attribute_code` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `source_model`='bakerloo_payment/source_paymentmethods';
```

Then either try to remove it from the admin panel, `Customers -> Attributes -> Manage Customer Attributes` or directly from the DB, after you made sure you have proper backups.